# Define type parameters with static members

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create some utility classes for my RESTful web-service to reduce the amount of boilerplate code.

Here is simplified example of my utility classes:

```
class Model {
    public static async findAll(options: any) {
        return Promise.resolve([]);
    }
}

class Service<M> {
    public model: M;
    // this will fix the following problem with "findAll". But we can't access "User" model members in "UsersService"
    // public model: typeof Model;

    constructor(options: { model: any }) {
        this.model = options.model;
    }

    public async find(params?: any): Promise<any> {
        return this.model.findAll(params); // error: Property 'findAll' does not exist on type 'M'
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
class User extends Model {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    constructor(options: any) {
        super();

        this.firstName = options.firstName;
        this.lastName = options.lastName;
    }
}

class UsersService extends Service<typeof User> {
    constructor() {
        super({ model: User });
    }

    public async customMethod() {
        const users = this.find({});

        const newUser = new this.model({ firstName: 'foo', lastName: 'bar' });

        newUser.firstName // ok
        newUser.lastName // ok
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how should I define type parameters for "Service" class, so I can access "findAll" in "Service" class and also access "firstName" and "lastName" fields in "UsersService"?

If I define type parameter as "M extends Model", then I still can't access static members.

[REPL example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiaBvAUNH0AOArgEYgCWw0EALmFedJAJ4B2FAZqc4gIIggAU8PHXjMIALgbNGASgzZcigE7IqBJc2gAFJfAC2pCMgB0KiPBAA3ZPwDaAXRkBuBTgC+mD5lCQYAZWQlS3JkAB5YAD55RUISej0kVElYF0UAejToKgALQ2gAd1I+aA4ADyzs5BKLEHhC5gBzfF0SZD0C0hzoACIOLl4QbuNoACECKgKq4DBmAHIJsGBgZCgegFUjJW7oBJQ0PTaiQJhOdc2IAKCQ7tdoDPxiMgpdpKzGPGR4NjhEkBdb4CiahKAjAKjwJSCYSkIGSdA7X6SGaMaBuORYRSKHKGYwvNAAXmgQhEYlxv1SuC8MUe9CYrBKnEQ-DwYCUYD0EAA-EjpDJJDp9IYwsiohjMTgVGoNBUcXjjH0eHxmaz2RBnHdMoFdEp+boPkoqCjZgqBrNoIh4CtoMx4BNkKVDBNRG8PtBZrBZrcPF4MphvOBVhtAtB7VRkFwYAg9tFcBwlNQAHLs5CSYGcBoUnABqhJg6pqhKdP-RSAsQF0HgyHEmFiHmyGPiiAEfX8Zx+8U4bEQeWkeM55PQQnVoE9vu55CZzFd4zZ8eDonQkez5OT71+nyB86XYLLEOlMMR6DbkKhQ0fL7QINKUUAoHlsEQ1sNzFNlvwvGSK+otuKKm4WJPAwEAsBQwAENQ+iwKo2RIE+YriqW1DQOBxzztOCr8OgaLFh2iETMwyD5F+hIEfkMrdnimEMmOyaSMa8DwLMAA00DLnmbpEKyZrYe2HakVeo6JgO9zwAA1rcij8ZsM6QP2BwakS4m-p4QA)

Comment: Closest I can get is `class Service<M extends typeof Model> {`, which makes everything work except I get a `Type 'typeof User' does not satisfy the constraint 'typeof Model'.` which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I am not certain, but constructors are typically not part of the 'type' of a class. It might be helpful to define an interface that defines a `new()` function , so everything implementing that interface is forced to implement the constructor signature in a compatible manner.

Comment: @Evert actualy "Model" is  a library function, so it might be a bit messy to duplicate these declarations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class Model {
    public static async findAll(options: any) {
        return Promise.resolve([]);
    }

    public f(): string { return ''}
}

type AnyConstructor = new (...args: unknown[]) => unknown;
type StaticProperties<T extends AnyConstructor> = Pick<T, keyof T>;

class Service<M extends StaticProperties<typeof Model>> {
    public model: M;

    constructor(options: { model: M }) {
        this.model = options.model;
    }

    public async find(params?: any): Promise<any> {
        return this.model.findAll(params); // error: Property 'findAll' does not exist on type 'M'
    }
}

class User extends Model {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    constructor(options: any) {
        super();

        this.firstName = options.firstName;
        this.lastName = options.lastName;
    }
}

class UsersService extends Service<typeof User> {
    constructor() {
        super({ model: User });
    }

    public async customMethod() {
        const users = this.find({});

        const newUser = new this.model({ firstName: 'foo', lastName: 'bar' });

        newUser.firstName // ok
        newUser.lastName // ok
    }
}
```

As of now, creating an interface for static properties is kind of a mess. Hopefully, [this proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892) could make it easier.

Comment: Yes, this solution solves the problem with error, but then I have to write duplicate code ("Model" is a library class and contains a lot of static methods that can be used). I thought there is a more convenient solution. Probably I should review the usage of "Model" in my code.

Comment: I see. To remove duplication, you can create a helper that extracts static properties from constructors. This way you could just read them from `Model` without redefining them. I updated my answer with an example implementation.